# Use latest version of System.Net.Http in .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

The latest version of [`System.Net.Http`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/) on nuget is 4.3.4. But even the latest .Net Framework 4.8 ships with 4.2.0 of this library.

Even if I add the nuget package Visual Studio 2019 still picks up the `System.Net.Http.dll` from the .Net Framework installation files.

Is there any way to get around this?

.Net Core still does not have designer support for wpf and winforms that's why i need this to work with .net framework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Totally agree with you that this is confusing, but at the end binding redirection is your friend here used with your app.config / web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The above snippet forces whatever version comes in with your code that the version which is specified in "newVersion" attribute will be used.

The table below gives you some insights on the versioning differences.

[image: Mapping NuGet - BindingRedirect]

Some info on the [binding redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) by Microsoft itself.

Comment: hi thank you for answering... I changed the newVersion to `4.2.1.0` which is apparently the dll version of nuget 4.3.4. Then i manually copied the dll from packages folder to my bin directory but it said `The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference`. Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: in your case the bindingRedirect should look like the following `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1.0" newVersion="4.2.1.0" />`

Answer (score 5):

I have several projects where I was forced to install .NETStandard 2.0 because some other package was dependent on it, even though we're just using .NET 4.6.1. After a long time Googling (and sorry, I can't point you to where I found this because it was done so long ago), I was able to figure out that when you have packages that are using the netstandard2 version of the assemblies, VS will automatically force `System.Net.Http` to version 4.2.0, even if you don't have the binding redirect as explained by Dimi. Packages that install themselves with netstandard2 include `System.Buffers`, `System.Collections.Immutable`, `System.Memory`, `System.Runtime.Compilers.Unsafe`, and `System.Text.Encodings.Web` (I'm sure there are more).

What I ended up having to do was manually edit the .csproj files and force these assemblies to use the netstandard1.x versions.

```
<Reference Include="System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Memory.4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Memory.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

So for example, the hint path for `System.Memory` points to the `netstandard2.0` folder. If you go to your packages folder for, you'll find that there are three flavors of this assembly: `netcoreapp211`, `netstandard1.1`, and `netstandard2.0`. I don't want the first one because I'm not using .NET Core, so I changed it to use 1.1 instead. After doing that for all assemblies that point to `netstandard2.0` to 1.0 or 1.1 (whichever is available), VS then allowed me to use the `System.Net.Http.4.3.4` package that I actually had installed.

I really don't know why this works, as I know almost nothing about .NETStandard, but it does.

Comment: This is because it looks up the what is inside the packagereferences folder located under  **%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages**

Comment: @DimiTakis I don't have that folder, probably because I'm still using packages.config, not packagereference,json.

Answer (score 3):

.NET can be very painful to develop as new versions of System packages are released, and you happen to use a library that adopts the new version. The new versions contains some additional APIs that the library uses, and if you use an older one, your program may still run, but crash at run time with `MethodNotFoundException` because the older DLL doesn't contain a particular method defined.

Even when you ship the latest version, you can still have a problem. For instance, one library uses System.Net.Http 4.2.0.0 another uses System.Net.Http 4.3.0.0, and you ship 4.3.0.0 with the application, the library that uses 4.2.0.0 will look for *exactly* version 4.2.0.0, and crash your program since you didn't have the same version included. The .NET team anticipated this and allow your program to *redirect* 4.2.0.0 to 4.3.0.0, this is known as a binding redirect.

Once you have a lot of binding redirects, it's impossible to manage by hand.

The best way is to have the computer do this automatically for you. Update the `.csproj` file so it contains an `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects` tag.

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
     <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Next, update your `app.config` or `web.config` and remove all binding redirects

```xml
<configuration>
  <runtime>
     <!-- REMOVE THE ENTIRE SECTION START -->
     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <!-- REMOVE ENTIRE SECTION END -->
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

When you build the application, and you inspect the `bin\Debug\YOURAPP.exe.config` you will find binding redirects has been added automatically so that all the libraries look for a single version of a DLL.

### Additional steps for Web Applications

If you have a `web.config`, then the process is different. Since Web.config needs to be shipped to the production machine, it needs the correct assembly binding redirect added. Visual Studio will compute the assembly binding redirects required, and show a build warning.

When you double click on the build warning, the correct assembly binding redirect will be added to your web.config.

### Additional checks

If you use `packages.config`, then you should check that your `.csproj`
is referencing the same versions of nuget defined in the `packages.config`.

However, if you are building an .exe, and not a web application, I recommend you convert your project to use PackageReference instead. Visual Studio will ensure the same version is referenced automatically and you will not have to check.

Answer (score 2):

Not the answer for this question, but related and important:
According to [official post on github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/65005#issuecomment-1104956294), you should avoid using the nuget package of System.Net.Http. If they had a choice to go back, they would never publish that .dll alone again.

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason, System.Net.Http dll in my case had "Copy local" set to **true**. It was **true** in two projects, and only that dll of all references. It looks suspicious that Visual Studio or NuGet set it that way. When I set it to false, my runtime problems went away. And I removed bindingRedirect from app.config, I couldn't make it work with that.